# Subgroups that can be proven?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

How do you show all subgroups of $A_5$ have order less or equal than 12?

I know you can use this lemma:

If G is a finite group, and H does not equal G is a subgroup of G such that oG $/|/$ i(H)! then H must contain a nontrivial normal subgroup of G. In particular, G cannot be simple.

/|/ means it is not |.

I know this proof. How would you do this example though. Can someone please show me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following theorem could help us:

> Theorem: Let $G$ be a simple group and let $H<G$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then if $[G:H]=n$ then $G\hookrightarrow A_n$.

Now letting $G=A_5$ and any other subgroup with the order $>12$ make us a contradiction.

Edit: I didn't see the *excluded* case of non-abelian groups. So we assume that $G$ is non abelian group.

Comment: +1, although it does not work for the rather trivial case when $G$ is of order $2$, and $H = \{ e \}$. Perhaps you can add *nonabelian*.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thanks Andreas. Sometimes, I don't see the trivial cases.

Comment: @Babak I would like to see the excluded case of non-abelian groups if you do not mind. Thanks, I get this proof. I did prove this by contradiction too.

Comment: @Andreas I would like to see your way too. It seems good to know what you just said. Seems like a good proof.

Comment: @9959, my argument is exactly Babak S.'s argument. You first embed $G$ into $S_{n}$, so there is a subgroup $H \le S_{n}$ isomorphic to $G$. Then note that $H \cap A_{n}$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Since $G \cong H$ is simple,  either $H \cap A_{n} = H$, so $H \le A_{n}$, or $H \cap A_{n} = \{ 1 \}$, and then $H$ has order $2$.

Comment: @BabakS.: even added the nice update! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks. It was a flash in my mind that I could see what Andreas had seen.

Comment: $\Large + 1 \;\ddot\smile\;$

Comment: @amWhy: The plus $\huge{\text{one}}$ makes me more power. :^)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for examples of all of its subgroups. 
[perhaps this link may help you](http://math.stanford.edu/~jelicata/109hw9sol.pdf)